# I want to install a water faucet and sink in my barn

Tags: plumbing, barn

We live in rural Ohio on 15 acres. Our water comes from a well (modern casing with submersible pump). The well is located next to the house. The house has a basement.

Ten years ago I had a pole barn built. The barn is about 300 feet from the house. I would like to have a water faucet and sink in the barn, mainly so I can mop the floor. How do I go about doing it?

One idea is to run a water line from the house to the barn. But that would mean drilling a hole in the foundation, and I really don't want to do that.

The other idea is to "tap in" to the water line between the house and well. I like this idea because I don't have to drill a hole in our home's foundation. But I am not sure about the proper way to go about it. Would I need a shutoff valve near the tap location?

Yet another idea is to have another well drilled, near the barn. But that's pricey.

Just looking for ideas.

Comment: where are the pressure tank and the pump's pressure-operated switch located?

Comment: Is the barn heated? If not, in winter plumbing might freeze or burst. There *are* special valves that are below-grade, i.e., below the frost line, with a long stem to a handle above, but would that be applicable for your use?

Comment: Is your well water treated?  Do you need your barn water to be potable, or is it *solely* for mopping?